# Cambiar idioma de datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables

Estoy utilizando Datatables de jQuery, algo muy sencillo y funciona genial.

Tengo estas librerías:

```
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<!--botones DataTables-->   
<script src="js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--Libreria para exportar Excel-->
<script src="js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<!--Librerias para exportar PDF-->
<script src="js/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<!--Librerias para botones de exportación-->
<script src="js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
```

Y de paso:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Pero resulta que en la tabla existen letreros como "show", "search" y demás en Inglés, yo quiero editarlos para tener toda mi página en español.

Alguno de casualidad sabe cómo hacerlo? 
Gracias chicos :)

Comment: La pregunta es poco clara y agregar todas las librerías que estás usando ayuda poco. Deberías incluir sólo las que tenga relación directa con la pregunta, además que deberías indicar que es lo que has buscado/investigado. Más detalles en [ask].

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Si quieres evitar cargar más enlaces o hacer peticiones puedes manejar los textos directamente de la siguiente manera:

> **Nota:** las propiedades de `language` pueden variar dependiendo de la versión de dataTables, en este caso funcionan bien con la versión más reciente (*1.10.15*)

```
var table = $('#DataTablesClientes').DataTable({
    language: {
        "decimal": "",
        "emptyTable": "No hay información",
        "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Entradas",
        "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Entradas",
        "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
        "infoPostFix": "",
        "thousands": ",",
        "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Entradas",
        "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "processing": "Procesando...",
        "search": "Buscar:",
        "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
        "paginate": {
            "first": "Primero",
            "last": "Ultimo",
            "next": "Siguiente",
            "previous": "Anterior"
        }
    },
    ....
});
```

En este [apartado](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language) de la documentación obtienes mas informacion de `language`

Comment: muchas gracias increible

Answer (score 8):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Usando la opción [`language.url`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.url) se puede configurar un archivo `JSON` para con la traducción.

  - **[Opcional]** Usar el [`plugin Spanish translation`](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/Spanish) que ya existe.

Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "language": {
      "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json"
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Posición</th>
                <th>Oficina</th>
                <th>Edad</th>
                <th>Fecha de inicio</th>
                <th>Salario</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Hola @Marcos sabes como pasar a español es mensaje que tira cuando usas el botón  ´Copiar´

Answer (score 8):

Para la versión 1.10.16, eliminaba las opciones para exportar, para habilitar.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table').dataTable( {
        "language": {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Spanish.json"
        },
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Información en el siguiente [enlace](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html).

Answer (score 0):

Otra posibilidad es colocar un enlace pero a un archivo local:

```
    "language": {
  "url": "idiomas/espaniol.json"
}
```

y en el cuerpo del archivo **espaniol.json** colocas la traducción (en formato JSON) que corresponda:

```
{
    "decimal": "",
    "emptyTable": "No hay información",
    "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Entradas",
    "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Entradas",
    "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
    "infoPostFix": "",
    "thousands": ",",
    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Entradas",
    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "processing": "Procesando...",
    "search": "Buscar:",
    "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
    "paginate": {
        "first": "Primero",
        "last": "Ultimo",
        "next": "Siguiente",
        "previous": "Anterior"
    }
},
```

Queda mas limpio el .js