# Modificar texto de select en Datatables jQuery

Tags: datatables

Buen día, he investigado en el código del plugin jQuery datatables para lograr modificar el texto "Mostrar registros" pero no encuentro en donde se genera, ¿Alguien lo ha encontrado o desarrollado algo para modificarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes hacerlo mediante el archivo de configuración de lenguaje, es decir 
 `$('#mitabla').DataTable({  language: { "sLengthMenu":     "Ver _MENU_ filas"}});`  modificas el ver y filas por lo que desee mostrar.  Las demás opcionesconfigurables están especificadas en [las opciones de lenguaje](http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json) o directamente en la [siguiente pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/87338/cambiar-idioma-de-datatables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La estructura para eso es asi:

```
$('#mitabla').DataTable({
            "paging": true,
            "lengthChange": true,
            "searching": true,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": true,
            "autoWidth": true,
            "lengthMenu": [ [5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10,25, 50, "Mostrar Todo"] ],
            "language": unJSONdelastraducciones
        });
```

Aqui te pongo un ejemplo completo de como traducir datatables:

primero hare el JSON del idioma:

```
let idioma=

            {
                "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
                "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
                "sEmptyTable":     "NingÃºn dato disponible en esta tabla",
                "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sInfoPostFix":    "",
                "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
                "sUrl":            "",
                "sInfoThousands":  ",",
                "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst":    "Primero",
                    "sLast":     "Ultimo",
                    "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                },
                "oAria": {
                    "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                    "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                },
                "buttons": {
                    "copyTitle": 'Informacion copiada',
                    "copyKeys": 'Use your keyboard or menu to select the copy command',
                    "copySuccess": {
                        "_": '%d filas copiadas al portapapeles',
                        "1": '1 fila copiada al portapapeles'
                    },

                    "pageLength": {
                    "_": "Mostrar %d filas",
                    "-1": "Mostrar Todo"
                    }
                }
            };
```

y ya en tu tabla pones asi:

```
$('#miTabla').DataTable({
            "paging": true,
            "lengthChange": true,
            "searching": true,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": true,
            "autoWidth": true,
            "lengthMenu": [ [5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10,25, 50, "Mostrar Todo"] ],
            "language": idioma
        });
```

En tu ejemplo me parece que usaras material design asi que te adjunto unos ejemplos que tengo en mi codepen:

Datatable material design
https://codepen.io/coderalexis/pen/JpzgNM

Materializecss Datatable material design
https://codepen.io/coderalexis/pen/zRXOvL

Materializecss Datatable material design2
https://codepen.io/coderalexis/pen/eVoOLQ