# No se visualizan los botones

Tags: ajax, mvc, datatables, materialize

no se por qué razón no me aparecen los botones de copear y Excel, he mirado la documentación de datatables vs lo que tengo y según yo esta bien , en la solución estoy implementando materialize, no sé si esto influya. Y algunas librerías de jquery, agradezco cualquier luz o consejo que me puedan brindar.

mis js:

```
<!--importando jquery y materialize-->    
<script src="jquery/jquery v3.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- dataTables permite crear filtros y  ordenar -->
<script src="jquery/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js">
// <script src="js/buttons.html5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

mi html:

```
<table id="CLEnfermedades" class="centered striped responsive-table">
                        <thead>
                          <th>Semana</th>
                          <th>% Nacional</th>
                          <th>Acaros</th>
                          <th>Afidos</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php
                        $ye = date("Y"); 
                        $sql="
                        select porcentaje.ano, porcentaje.Nsemana,internacional.ano as  Ainternacional ,Porcentajecl as PNacional,Acaros,Afidos,Babosa,Botrytis,Fusarium,Hetero,Minador,Trips,Trozador,
                        Velloso,Abierto,DosPuntos,Amarillamiento,CabezaPeque,Corto,Debil,Decolorado,Deformado,Delgados,PetaloQuemado,PuntasQuemado,Rajado,Torcido,Toxicidad,TInternacional 
                        from porcentaje
                        right join internacional
                        on porcentaje.Nsemana = internacional.Nsemana 
                        where porcentaje.ano = ".$ye." and internacional.ano = ".$ye." and  porcentaje.TFlor = 'CL' 
                        order by porcentaje.Nsemana desc;                        
                        ";
                        $resul=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
                        while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($resul)){?>
                            <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $mostrar['Nsemana'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $mostrar ['PNacional'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $mostrar ['Acaros'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $mostrar ['Afidos'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $mostrar ['Babosa'] ?></td>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

mi script:

```
  $('#CLEnfermedades').DataTable({
      "order": [[0,"desc"]],
      "scrollX": true,
      "dom": 'Bfrtip',
      "buttons": [
        'copyHtml5',
        'excelHtml5',
      ],
      "language":{
        "url":"//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.21/i18n/Spanish.json"}
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

yo tuve un problema al momento de integrar la url del JSON del idioma español usando materialize igual, al agregarlo el select de "show entries" desapareció solo aparecía el label como tal, trate de solucionarlo desde el js pero me pasaba lo mismo, llegué a esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/175495 y abrí uno de los enlaces que proporcionaba en el ejemplo, el segundo para ser exactos, y vi que el tenía en css: `.dataTables_length select { display: inline-block;}` lo agregué a mi archivo css y el select volvió a aparecer, el usuario también agrega un par más de elementos css pero es en cuestiones de diseños, con agregar la primera parte mostrado en el código pude visualizar lo que pretendía, no tengo mucho conocimientos pero fue la forma en que gracias a Dios pude solucionarlo, a lo mejor esto pueda ayudarte un poco y la cuestión que quieres visualizar se deba a un cambio en CSS. Saludos y espero logres solucionar el problema que estás teniendo. Todo el crédito al usuario: **[José Alexis Cruz Solar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/12715/jos%C3%A9-alexis-cruz-solar)** por su respuesta y sus ejemplos